# Convert account level forecast into portfolio forecast by manipulating data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an input data frame with Revenue forecasts of a customer for 4 months from his acquisition as below
[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7E0C.png)

Say we onboard 1 customer with above forecast every month for the next 4 months , I want to have aggregate Revenue estimate of the portfolio every month.

**Total Row** is my expected output
[Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bddxN.png)

I need help in manipulating my input dataframe at account level into portfolio level

Comment: Please make an earnest attempt and return with any questions/issues. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I understand this is not  a code-writing service. I was expecting a link to a meaningful existing thread or high level concept of how to get it done. Sample data was only to keep my question unambiguous

Comment: Exact SO flag: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I am new here. My first question infact. Will learn the rules quick